# Prestashop WebService adding ID of category or product

Tags: service, web, prestashop

Is where any way to add id_category or id_prodocut not by auto incerment but by setting number my self?

This is my code:

```
unset($resources ->position);
unset($resources ->date_add);
unset($resources ->date_upd);
unset($resources ->level_depth);
unset($resources ->nb_products_recursive);
$resources ->id_category = '666';
$resources ->id_parent = '118';
$resources ->name ->language[0][0] = 'Nuaja Kategorija';
$resources ->link_rewrite->language[0][0] = 'Sudu-malunas';
$resources ->active = 1;
$resources ->id_shop_default = 1;
$resources ->is_root_category = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly No! Most of the REST applications don't allow REST consumer to set the resource ID.